# Is it possible to have a shortcut to switch to the nth xfce-tasklist window in Xubuntu like in Windows?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce

One of my favorite features in Windows is the ability to press -1 to switch to the leftmost window in the "Window buttons", -2 to go to the 2nd one, and so on, as opposed to alt-tabbing through everything.

I remember reading that I could assign a script to a key combination to switch to a specifiy window **title**, but I'd like to be able to switch based on its position in the taskbar.

(Also I think Unity can do this, but I'd really rather stick with XFCE)

Comment: I haven't used windows in 10 years, are you talking about something like work spaces? Or something more like what alt-tab does? I'm sure its a key-binding issue. Are you referring to a specific task list?

Comment: Kind of like alt-tab, but you skip to the n-th window by pressing Super-n, based on their order in the taskbar.

Comment: Ill give it some thought. what does $echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP  say?

Comment: @DmitryNarkevich It is a pitty you already set your bounty, you could have saved your bounty, it was already bountied earlier: http://askubuntu.com/a/560158/72216 on this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/557084/any-way-to-open-windows-from-the-windows-bar-using-a-shortcut

Comment: Dmitry, can you confirm the above question solves your problem?

Comment: Beautifully :') thank you so much
@JacobVlijm post it as an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: @DmitryNarkevich I am afraid I will be flagged if I post the same answer twice :). I am (very) happy though the answer is usefull.

Comment: @Seth I think it does :)