# Any way to open windows from the windows bar using a shortcut

Tags: 14.04, scripts, shortcut-keys, xfce

Any way to open windows from the windows bar using a shortcut? for example to open the first window on the left Ctrl+1, to open the second window on the left Ctrl+2.

Im using xfce4 at this moment, but if under xfce4 is not possible, is there any other desktop environment that permits this?

Since I have several windows open for the same application, I not searching for sortcuts related to the application but as I say below, to the window.

Comment: You mean switch to windows, depending on their position on the screen? What would that exactly be, 4 segments (upper-left, down-left etc) or 2 segments (left/right)?. Another option: relative to each other? All can be done. Interesting.

Comment: @JacobVlijm no, depending on the position on the taskbar, from left to right or viceversa.

Comment: I see. I think it can be done.

Comment: I'm also asking [which desktop environments support switching among windows with Super+0..9](http://askubuntu.com/questions/813262/which-desktop-environments-allow-switching-among-windows-with-supernumbers?noredirect=1#comment1236408_813262)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a little script and a small surgery on your system, it can be arranged exactly as you describe.

#### Ingredients

1. `wmctrl`; it possibly needs to be installed.
2. The script below
3. `xprop`, to get the window properties. This is already installed on your system.
4. Settings changes in xfce panel settings
5. Additional keyboard shortcuts

#### How to set up

- Install `wmctrl`:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install wmctrl
  ```
- Create a directory `~/bin` (`/home/<yourname>/bin`). Copy the script below into an empty file, save it as `panel_navigate` (no extension) in `~/bin` and *make it executable*.
- Change panel settings:
  Go to Settings Manager > "Panel" > "Items" (tab) > "Window Buttons" >

  - "Sorting order" > Choose: *Timestamp*
  - "Window Grouping" > Choose: "Never"
  - Make sure "Show windows from all workspaces or viewports" is *un*ticked

  [image]
- Add Keyboard shortcuts:
  go to Settings Manager > "Keyboard" > "Application Shortcuts", choose "Add". Add the command:

  ```
  panel_navigate 1
  ```

  Set it to the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>

  [image]
- Now you can choose:

  - to repeat this procedure to add `panel_navigate 2` under <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> and so on (until 9)

  (save option) *or* (if you are not afraid to edit config files manually):

  - you can edit the file:

    ```
    ~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchanel-xml/xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml
    ```

    in which the keyboard shortcuts (in `xfce`) are stored. Open the file with `mousepad` and look for a line like:

    ```
    <property name="&lt;Primary&gt;1" type="string" value="panel_navigate 1"/>
    ```

    Copy the line, paste it on the next line (insert) and change both occurrences of 1 into 2, so you'll get:

    ```
    <property name="&lt;Primary&gt;1" type="string" value="panel_navigate 1"/>
    <property name="&lt;Primary&gt;2" type="string" value="panel_navigate 2"/>
    ```

  and so on..

  Make sure the indent is exactly the same. Repeat the procedure until 9.

Log out and back in and it should work:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>

[image]

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>

[image]

And so on...

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import subprocess
import sys

def get_value(command):
    return subprocess.check_output(["/bin/bash", "-c", command]).decode("utf-8").strip()

def run_command(command):
    subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "-c", command])

current_workspace = [l for l in get_value("wmctrl -d").splitlines() if l.split(" ")[2] == "*"][0][0]
wlist_ids = [item.split()[0:4] for item in get_value("wmctrl -l").splitlines()]
relevant = [item for item in wlist_ids if item[1] == current_workspace]
panel = []
for item in relevant:
    data = get_value("xprop -id "+item[0])
    if ("_TYPE_NORMAL" in data, "TYPE_DIALOG" in data).count(True) == 1:
        panel.append(item)
try:
    window = panel[int(sys.argv[1])-1][0]
    run_command("wmctrl -ia "+window)
except IndexError:
    pass
```

#### Explanation

The solution is an opportunistic one. It occurred to me that the windowlist, called by the command `wmcrl -l`, is  ordered by the age of the windows. By making the xfce panel do the same (settings), both orders are corresponding perfectly. What the script does is creating a window list, filtering out the "real", visible windows (with `xprop`) and switch to a chosen window by the command `panel_navigate`, with the number of the window (from the left to the right) as an agrument.

#### Issues

I noticed one exception: the IDLE (python interpreter) windows have pid 0 and their properties can not be "researched" by `xprop`. The windows do not appear in the windowlist and are skipped by the script.

#### Note

Although the Key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+`<number>` didn't raise any errors while testing, it might conflict with some applications. It might be safer to choose (e.g.) 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>

Comment: @tirengarfio, I made an important improvement since the last update: now the script only lists windows of the *current* workspace, to prevent confusion/incorrect numbering if windows are spread over workspaces. Make sure  "Show windows from all workspaces or viewports" (panel settings) is unticked.

Answer (score 2):

*Not sure for the same application*, but in `Unity` you can switch applications with `super+number`, as for example, `super + 1` = first item on the launcher, `super + 2` = the second item of the launcher, `super + n` = the nth item of the launcher. This also helps to open any item placed on the launcher, like if nautilus is the first item of the launcher, `super + 1` will open up nautilus file manager.