# Xubuntu - how to make win+(number) open app shown in top bar?

Tags: xubuntu, shortcuts, productivity

I'm using xubuntu 18.04. At the moment the top bar looks like this

[image]

I'd like to have the first (Xubuntu...) firefox window open when I click `win+1`, and the second (Analytics...) when I click `win+2`. How can this be done?

Comment: Not sure how much xfce changed in the meantime, but https://askubuntu.com/questions/557084/any-way-to-open-windows-from-the-windows-bar-using-a-shortcut. Please mention how and if it works out.

Comment: @JacobVlijm, it does require that I change the sorting of the windows to "by timestamp" though, I'd like to avoid that

Comment: Any specific reason to? Anyway, I recon the alternatives are scarce, and this was a hack already. The question was acompanied by a bounty back then, and no other solution came up.

Comment: @JacobVlijm, no reason other than being used to the default grouping. It's a shame xfce4-panel doesn't let you list items. If nothing comes up, I'll try to use your solution, thanks